# delete a randomly located nonempty directory using rdir

Tags: rmdir

Here is my scenario. I am trying to delete a randomly located directory called “Cache”. This directory will contain subfolders as well as files. Here is the directory structure. As you can see Firefox is creating a random profile directory. Is it possible to insert a variable for user_a as well as the ###.Default directory I would like to do this using a script.

Thank you

> E:\CitrixProfiles\Win7\user_A\UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\8rbtev35.default\Cache
>
> E:\CitrixProfiles\Win7\user_B
>   \UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5m639z2j.default\Cache
>
> E:\CitrixProfiles\Win7\user_Z
>   \UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5cx5z2j.default\Cache